# What is the definition of different regression bugs in regression test for a software?

Tags: regression, regression-testing

there are 3 regression bugs while doing a regression test for a software. "local","unmasked" and "remote". Does any one know the definition of each? 
thanks

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more information than that if you want any meaningful answers.

Comment: Isn't it 4? masked local, masked remote, unmasked local, unmasked remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case anyone like me needs the answer is this:

- **Local**: Bug appears in newly written code.
- **Unmasked**: Newly written code causes bug already in code to manifest itself.
- **Remote**: Newly written code causes error in other part of software, e.g. by passing illegal values to function or closing file that is still needed. Difficulty is tracing the cause of th error.